# passing new constructed control to the function

Tags: c#, .net

I'm adding new controls to the main control this way:

```
Controls.Add(new ComboBox()
{
    Text = "dsnfsdbfsdbfjsdbfsdjbfsmdfbsdbfsbf",
    Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right,
    Width = DropDownWidth(/*Here should be smth. similar to "this" but for currently created combobox*/)
});

public int DropDownWidth(ComboBox myCombo)
{
    int maxWidth = 0, temp = 0;
    foreach (var obj in myCombo.Items)
    {
        temp = TextRenderer.MeasureText(obj.ToString(), myCombo.Font).Width;
        if (temp > maxWidth)
        {
            maxWidth = temp;
        }
    }
    return maxWidth;
}
```

I want to pass the new Combobox to the function and get the desired width.

Is there some keyword similar to `this`, but for newly created ComboBox which I can pass to the function?

**Please** no workarounds! I know that I can create the Combobox first, fill it with properties and add to control in the next step. 
Only short form is interesting for now.

Thank you!

Comment: Also, since the `Items` collection is (in your snippet) quite empty, that code will simply return `0`. How do you expect to use this, in a proper case? =)

Comment: @J.Steen it's empty for now, this is not the full code, just wanted to know if there is something like "this" for this case :)

Comment: You could write your own ComboBox class, and then in the constructor call that method that sets your width. At this point the object WILl exist and you will be able to set all the properties you wish

Comment: @EricFrick I'm pretty sure the constructor is called before the object initialiser. Meaning, any items added in the object initialiser won't exist, yet.

Comment: @J.Steen I know, but in the constructor you can set the width value to a private field, and then expose it with a public property pointing to that field.

Comment: @EricFrick I'm still unsure how that helps in sending a non-existant reference to a method in an object initialiser? You could provide an example in your answer, and I'm sure it'd be appreciated by anyone coming looking for this kind of information. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can't use a reference of an object until it's actually created, which it technically isn't in the object initialiser because it's part of the creation statement. A "workaround" is *required* in this case.

Something like...

```
var myTextArray = new[] { "Hi", "ho", "Christmas" }

Controls.Add(new ComboBox()
{
    Text = "dsnfsdbfsdbfjsdbfsdjbfsmdfbsdbfsbf",
    Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right,
    Width = DropDownWidth(myTextArray, this.Font)
});
```

...where `this` of course is your `Form` or other parent `Control`.

And the modified `DropDownWidth` method would read something like...

```
public int DropDownWidth(object[] objects, Font font)
{
    int maxWidth = 0, temp = 0;
    foreach (var obj in objects)
    {
        temp = TextRenderer.MeasureText(obj.ToString(), font).Width;
        if (temp > maxWidth)
        {
            maxWidth = temp;
        }
    }
    return maxWidth;
}
```

Comment: That's a really good idea I wished to find here and was wondering about negative reaction. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass it to the function because it doesn't exists yet

For example @J.Steen:

```
    public class CustomCombo : System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
{
    private int _width;

    public int Width
    {
        get { return _width; }
        set { _width = value; }
    }


    public CustomCombo()
    {
        _width = getWidth(this);
    }
    public int getWidth(System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox combo)
    {
        //do stuff
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes, that's what I thought you meant. But the GetWidth() method needs to make use of the ComboBox's items. And if they haven't been assigned yet (as the object initialiser happens after the constructor), this won't work anyway. =)

Comment: @J.Steen well, passing array of strings as constructor parameter could work :)

Comment: @VladL Sure, sure. Now you're talking. But you could easily do that for your original snippet too, as long as you also passed a font object. =)

Comment: Please see edit. In my example, this refers to the initialized object so it will work

Comment: @J.Steen I could easily do whatever I want if I were sure, that object isn't created at the needed moment